Using Azure Graph API to get user details by Id, but the "Email Addresses" attribute (StringCollection) is always missing in the response
I am using the Azure Graph API to retrieve user details by their Id. However, I am encountering an issue where I am unable to obtain the value of the "Email Addresses" attribute, which is of the StringCollection data type.
B2C User Attributes

Despite successfully retrieving other user attributes, the "Email Addresses" field consistently missing from the response.
How to properly retrieve the "Email Addresses" attribute using the Azure Graph API? If there are specific query parameters or configurations required, kindly provide detailed instructions.

It's probably the otherMails property which is not returned by default, but it must be specified in $select query parameter.
GET /v1.0/users/{user_id}?$select=id,displayName,otherMails

User properties

Thanks for your response @user2250152.
I tried otherMails but it's giving me blank array(https://imgur.com/a/Cai4F6q). On B2C portal also in user properties I get no value under Other emails field(https://imgur.com/faUi2bM). But when I use userflow for signin and select Email Address, in JWT token I get emails array with email id.(https://imgur.com/55Z9Yxs)
